# Chart.js canvas rendered by ng-repeat does not show charts

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, chart.js

I am trying to create line chart with angularjs and chart.js below is my code:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet"
      href="http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script
    src="http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/node_modules/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script
    src="http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script
    src="http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/dist/angular-chart.js"></script>
<script>
    var app = angular.module('myAPP', ['chart.js'])
    app.controller('ChartController', function ($scope, $http) {
        $scope.counter = [1, 2, 3]
        $scope.labels = []
        $scope.data = []
        $scope.labels[ 1 ] = [1, 2, 3, 4]
        $scope.labels[ 2 ] = [1, 2, 3]
        $scope.labels[ 3 ] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
        $scope.data[ 1 ] = [1, 2, 0, 4]
        $scope.data[ 2 ] = [5, 1, 7]
        $scope.data[ 3 ] = [5, 6, 2, 8, 9]
        $scope.chartOptions = {
            legend: {
                display: true,
            },
            title: {
                display: true,
                text: 'title'
            }
        }
    })
</script>
<body ng-app="myAPP" ng-controller="ChartController">
<div ng-repeat="n in counter">
    <canvas
        class="chart chart-line"
        chart-options="chartOptions"
        chart-data="data['{{n}}']"
        chart-labels="labels['{{n}}']"
    />
</div>
</body>
```

here i am creating canvas using ng-repeat

```
<div ng-repeat="n in counter">
        <canvas
            class="chart chart-line"
            chart-options="chartOptions"
            chart-data="data['{{n}}']"
            chart-labels="labels['{{n}}']"
        />
    </div>
```

but unfortunately no chart is rendered, but when i type data and label tags manually like below, charts are shown.

```
<div ng-repeat="n in counter">
        <canvas
            class="chart chart-line"
            chart-options="chartOptions"
            chart-data="data['1']"
            chart-labels="labels['1']"
        />
</div>
```

below are 2 examples:

[working example](https://codepen.io/cnanury/pen/abvzpjN)

[not working example](https://codepen.io/cnanury/pen/LYpExJW)

would you please help me find out what am i doing wrong in "not working example"?

Answer (score 0):

You should get rid of the quotes and the curly brackets and it should work.

```
<div ng-repeat="n in counter">
    <canvas
        class="chart chart-line"
        chart-options="chartOptions"
        chart-data="data[n]"
        chart-labels="labels[n]"
    />
</div>
```

Comment: thanks uminder it works when n is only numbers but when i make it more complex for example like chart-data="data[n.text+"_"+n.id]" (imagine counter and variables contain the data ) it is not working